# After how much time the same configuration will repeat?

Tags: contest-math, physics, rotations

> A ball rotates at a rate **$r$** rotations  per second and simultaneously revolves around a stationary point **$O$** at a rate **$R$** revolutions per second **$(R<r)$**. The rotation and revolution are in the same sense. A certain point on the ball is in the line of the centre of the ball and point **$O$** at a certain time. This configuration repeats after a time

> $(1)\ $ $\frac{1}{r-R}$

> $(2)\ $ $\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{r}$

> $(3)\ $ $\frac{1}{r+R}$

> $(4)\ $ $\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{r}$

How do I solve this aptitude question? Thanks for your time.

**Source** $:$ CSIR NET JUNE $2019.$

Comment: Why the downvote? Can anybody please give me some hint?

Comment: The downvote is because you show no work of your own trying to answer the question. If you [edit] to show us how you got started and where you are stuck we may be able to help.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker I have forgotten most of these rotational stuffs I studied in high school. I am now a masters student of Pure Mathematics. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As rotation and revolution are both in the same direction (say, counterclockwise), the point will come in the line connecting centers after one complete rotation. Say that happens after part revolution of angle $\theta$ against one full revolution ($2\pi$). In that time the rotation has completed by $(2\pi + \theta)$ (more than one rotation of ($2\pi$).

One rotation takes $\frac{1}{r}$ second and one revolution takes $\frac{1}{R}$ second. Equating the time taken -

$\displaystyle \frac{2\pi + \theta}{2\pi r} = \frac{\theta}{2\pi R}$

Now please find $\theta$ and then plug in either Right Hand side or in Left Hand side to find the time.

Comment: Your $\theta = \frac {2\pi R} {r + R},$ which doesn't meet either of the given options. So you please check your argument once again. Thanku.

Comment: $\theta$ is angle, not time. Please read my last line.

Comment: Then according to you the answer would be $\frac {1} {r + R}.$ But the answer key suggests that it would be $\frac {1} {r - R}.$

Comment: Can you please share a diagram if you don't mind?

Comment: Please have a look at the question carefully. Instead $r \gt R.$

Comment: Just added a diagram.

Comment: Can you please mention where the point O lies? Is it A in your diagram?

Comment: @ManjoyDas yes it is point $A$ in my diagram

Comment: What is meant by the line "A certain point on the ball is in the line of the centre of the ball and point O at a certain time"? Because the centre of the ball and the point of revolution is same here.

Answer (score 0):

Given:
Frequency of rotation   = 'r' times/sec
Frequency of revolution = 'R' times/sec.
(the rotation and the revolution are in the same sense), hence
Relative frequency of rotation = (r-R) times/sec.
As per this relative frequency of rotation, the centre of the ball and the point of its surface come in line with the external fixed point O, at each full rotation.

Time taken for one full rotation = 1/f = 1/(r-R) in sec